# (c++/cli) C++ using C# dll to get any enum member name

Tags: c#, c++, enums, c++-cli, typeof

I'm using VS2010, I'm try to use a C# dll to  get any enum member name in C++,

My C# dll source code:

```
namespace CSharpFuncion
{
    public class CSFun
    {
        public string GetEnumName(Enum en)
        {
            return Enum.GetName(typeof(Enum), en);
        }
    }
}
```

My C++ code

```
#using "CSharpFuncion.dll"
using namespace CSharpFuncion;
CSFun ^ csFun = gcnew CSFun;
cout << csFun->GetEnumName(MyTestEnum::E_A) << endl;
```

Error message:

```
cannot convert parameter from 'MyTestEnum'  to 'System::Enum ^'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: is this `c++/cli`? if so can you edit your title and the tags

Comment: An important point is whether `MyTestEnum` is a managed or unmanaged enum

Comment: What does your MyTestEnum look like?

Comment: @Malachi  you mean `enum class`?  I can't use it in VS2010

Comment: @Ali  `public enum MyTestEnum { E_A = 1, E_B = 2, };`

Comment: @Malachi did I accidentally delete you comment? so if I want to declare a managed  enum I need to use `__value `,  and for using `__value ` I need change `/clr` to `/clr:oldSyntax`, that cause my C++ can't use C# dll

Comment: I deleted my own comment, because I'm unable to bring up my Visual Studio to verify stuff right now and don't wanna mislead you.  However what you're saying there is the direction I was going in

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
public enum MyTestEnum
{
        E_A = 1,
        E_B = 2
};
```

You need to make it

```
public enum class MyTestEnum
{
        E_A = 1,
        E_B = 2
};
```

So just add the `class` keyword.

And change `return Enum.GetName(typeof(Enum), en);` to `return en.ToString()`

Comment: It is worth noting that `enum class` was adopted by the C++11 standard.  The accessibility specifier (`public` here) is now crucial to distinguish between a native and managed enum type.  Beware that the OP's question is misleading, public is not valid on a native enum type.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant ... Yes that's correct indeed, forgot to add that remark. The syntax itself (public enum) is not valid C++ syntax anyway, so hopefully it's clear to the OP that this is a managed enum, not a native one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give `Enum.GetName(typeof(MyTestEnum ), 1);` to get the name of value (E_A) in that enum